# Aliasing a self join

Tags: mysql, alias, self-join

I have been working with MySQL and I have a question on self joins.

When you self join, do you need to alias both tables?  For example:

```
FROM customer c1, customer c2
```

Now I know this works, but it also seems to work with

```
FROM customer, customer c2
```

Is there any particular reason to alias both tables beyond readability? Is there something wrong with not aliasing one table?

Comment: Nothing wrong: as you verified, it does work. But it's often best to alias both, to avoid any reading ambiguity.

Comment: Unrelated but: you should start using explicit `JOIN` conditions in the `FROM` clause instead of implicit join conditions in the `where` clause

Comment: I agree. Alias both for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally, there's no benefit in aliasing both tables. However, aliasing both of them removes potential points of confusion and makes the query more readable.